# How to find a value in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my code:

```
mFirebaseDatabae = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mMessageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("memos");

serchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        mMessageReference.orderByChild("title").equalTo("z").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(SerchActivity.this, "print", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my Firebase tree:

[image]

Isn't it possible for the title to be printed only when the title is z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fatch like this way...

```
for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String title= (String) messageSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
}
```